# Retrieve the element P present in 2 div having same Class name using beautiful soup python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have 2 div named as **Col-block** 
now i want to retrieve the text inside P of these div and store in different Variables (there are Multiple div in a page with same class name) 
 Compatible Cartridge should be store in variable names as Iname and Ministry Of Railways should be stored in other variable named as "Dname"

```
<div class="col-block">
   <p><strong style="text-transform: none !important;">Item(s): </strong><span>Microcontroller Educational Kit</span></p>
   <p><strong>Quantity Required: </strong><span>5</span></p>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-block">
   <p><strong>Start Date: </strong><span>25-08-2020 02:56 PM</span></p>
   <p><strong>End Date: </strong><span>04-09-2020 03:00 PM</span></p>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. In the page you have mutliple `<div class="col-block">` that come in pairs and you want to get the information from every pair?

Comment: yes  there are around 40 div have same class name col-block and i want to store text of P in diffrent variables for eg: Item(s): p will be stored in variable Item and Ministry Of Railways should be stored in other variable named as "Dname"

Comment: You can retrieve all contents of both *div* tag in a list then use each element as desired or use `xpath` instead.

Comment: sorry i am new to pthon pls help

Comment: @AndrejKesely pls help

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists see this..

Comment: @Pooria_T https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists see this

Comment: @AkhilJain I cannot open the link (probably the server blocks everyone outside India).